# Is there a way to push the results of an adb query to a file?

Tags: adb

I have a couple of adb commands that I'm running in PowerShell. Specifically:

```
adb shell settings get secure bluetooth_address; adb get-serialno
```

Is there a way to do an 'adb push' of that data to a text file on the same tethered device?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
./adb shell settings get secure bluetooth_address > results.txt ; ./adb get-serialno >> results.txt ; ./adb push results.txt /path/to/save/file
```

**Explaination:** The results from the first 2 commands are saved in a file on your PC, then the file is pushed to your device.